# Can I see a record's sharing hierarchy without modifying the layout?

Tags: sharing, detail-page

To see the sharing hierarchy the "Sharing Hierarchy" action needs added to either the standard page layout or the Lightning record page layout. Can I view the sharing hierarchy without making this change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sharing Hierarchy button directs users to a particular URL for the record. In Lightning experience this URL is in the form of:

`https://my.domain.com/lightning/r/Object/Id/recordShareHierarchy`

Provided the user has permission to view sharing hierarchies, going to this URL will show you the hierarchy.